# Trying to execute something after a page is rendered not just loaded in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get the x,y location of a UI element on a wpf page ( not window). In order to make sure the rendering of the page is completed, I place the revoking of PointToScreen inside the Loaded listener. However i get this runtime exception:

This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource.

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        .....
         Point position = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));
        }
```

Please let me know what to do? Or could you provide an example how I can run dispatcher for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in or official way to do this. However you can use the [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907(v=vs.100).aspx) class as a workaround:

```
 private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => YOUR_THING_HERE), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
 }
```

The dispatcher will run when nearly all other operations are completed (which will include your rendering)

I had a similar problem myself so this answer is based off [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/ilich/archive/2012/10/16/running-code-when-windows-rendering-is-completed.aspx) blog article that solved it for me.

**EDIT: I was actually wrong**

There is a [ContentRendered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered(v=vs.110).aspx) event that serves this purpose.

Comment: There's also the [CompositionTarget.Rendering event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering(v=vs.110).aspx).