# Avoiding visual is not connected to a presentationsource on Point.ToScreen wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am getting an exception Visual is not connected to presentation source in my wpf application when switching display monitors or rdc.

I am already checking the visibility before trying using Point.ToScreen.
What else can i do to avoid the issue?What am i missing here.

"system.invalidoperationexception  .This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource"

```
if (_pinned && _parentControl != null && _parentControl.IsVisible &&
                (sender == null || !EventBlacklist.Contains(sender)))
            {
                Point location;

                try
                {
                    location = _parentControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
                }
                catch
                {
                    return;
                }
}
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmaNi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to execute something after a page is rendered not just loaded in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557863/trying-to-execute-something-after-a-page-is-rendered-not-just-loaded-in-wpf)

Comment: Show the errors and exceptions as text in the question.

Comment: added the error and exception